# Combining Method hiding and method overriding in C#

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, method-hiding

I just could not find a satisfactory explanation for this. So I thought it would help to post this at SO.

What happens when we combine `method hiding and overriding in C# ?`

For the below example :

```
class BaseClassA
{
    public virtual void showMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In BaseClass A ");
    }
}
class DerivedClassB : BaseClassA
{
    public override void showMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In DerivedClass B ");
    }
}

class DerivedClassC : DerivedClassB
{
    public new void showMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In DerivedClass C");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClassA a = new BaseClassA();
        a.showMessage();
        a = new DerivedClassB();
        a.showMessage();
        BaseClassA b = new DerivedClassC();
        b.showMessage();
        Console.ReadKey();   
    }
}
```

I am understanding the output of

```
 BaseClassA b = new DerivedClassC();
 b.showMessage();
```

[image]

Here's what I understand for `new` and `override` in C#

`New` - It hides the baseclass method. So even if baseclass reference variable points to a derived class object if that derived class hides the method, the output will be baseclass output only.

`Override` - It overrides the baseclass method. So even if baseclass reference variable points to a derived class object if that derived class overrides the method, the output will be derived class output.

But here how can even a `BaseClassA` reference variable point to a `DerivedClassC` object and print `DerivedClassB`'s output ?

Please explain in simple words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But here how can even a BaseClassA reference variable point to DerivedClassC object and it prints DerivedClassB's output ?

The code calls the method which is declared by `BaseClassA` but overridden by `DerivedClassB`. The method declared in `DerivedClassC` is a new method, entirely separate from the one declared in `BaseClassA`... as if it had a different name, in a way.

Effectively, think of it this way:

- If `DerivedClassC` didn't declare a `showMessage` method at all, it would inherit the implementation from `DerivedClassB`, right?
- Introducing a *new* method doesn't change the output because it's a separate method which isn't involved in overriding the method introduced in `DerivedClassA`. So the output is the same as with the previous step.

I think that trying `DerivedClassC` as just

```
class DerivedClassC : DerivedClassB
{
}
```

and understanding *that* output is the key to understanding the later behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But I did not get this part ... why have I think that DerivedClassC did not declare `showMessage()` ? Yes it would inherit the implementation from `DerivedClassB` but that inherits from `BaseClassA`. So would not `DerivedClassC` hides the method for `BaseClassA` ? Am I thinking wrong ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder: Yes, `DerivedClassC` hides the method from `BaseClassA`, but you're not calling the method on a variable of type `DerivedClassC`. If you had `DerivedClassC c = new DerivedClassC(); c.showMessage();` then you'd see "In DerivedClass C".

Comment: that's precisely my confusion. Why am I not calling that hidden method ? If `DerivedClassC : BaseClassA` and then `BaseClassA a = new DerviedClassC` then I would definitely see `In BaseClass A to be printed`. But why not here ? Just because `DerivedClassC : DerivedClassB` but `DerivedClassB : BaseClass A right ?` Am I missing something?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder: You're not calling it precisely because it's "new" - it *doesn't* override the previously-declared method. You're calling a method on an expression with compile-time type `BaseClassA`. It doesn't know about your new method, and you've explicitly said you're *not* overriding the existing method... so the method basically doesn't exist as far as that call is concerned.